# Kentico - Combine search indexes

Tags: kentico

I have 2 different sites - both runs on Kentico but don't have anything in common with separate servers, separate Kentico setup, license etc. Because the 2 businesses now belong to one organization, and we want to cross promote content between the two, including in the smart search results. My question is it possible to add the search index of one site to the other so that when people search they're searching for content on both sites. If yes, how can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version you're using you can [create a custom Azure Search index](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-azure-search) which will support what you're looking for.  But this is only available for v11 and newer.

With previous versions, you should be able to [create a custom index](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/integrating-azure-search-with-kentico) and take advantage of Azure Search as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in theory, you would have to copy the search index from one server to the other, and then you would have to manage the results to know the difference so you could link to the other site. I don't think the link in the search index includes the domain, but you could double check that.

Answer (score 0):

Did have a chance to take a look at page crawler index type? https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/creating-search-indexes/defining-page-indexes#Definingpageindexes-Configuringpagecrawlerindexes

See if it is possible to configure it for external domain.